# Will interrupted thread continue its transaction?

Tags: java, multithreading

Supposed I have a thread class like this:

```
public class ThreadClass extends Thread{
      Object object = new Object();    //relevant object

      public void run(){
          synchronized(object){
              if(/*condition is true*/){
                   //do transactions here
              }else{
                  try{
                      object.wait();
                   }catch(InterruptedException e){
                       //if thread was interrupted
                   }
              }

              //other transactions here
          }   
      }

}
```

If the current thread was interrupted, will it continue its transactions? Will it still go to line *other transactions here*? Thanks.

Comment: run the code through a debugger...as you step through it, you'll notice that it continues with its transactions, since the `InterruptedException` was caught and effectively "swallowed', but if another interrupt is issued after this during the other transactions, it will kill the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the current thread was interrupted, will it continue its transactions?

Yes, however the interrupted flag will be set (calling `Thread.interrupted()` would return true), but this will not affect the code that is executing.

> Will it still go to line other transactions here?

Yes, for the same reason as above. Other transactions will also be executed if `object.wait()` is executed and then the `InterruptedException` is caught, assuming you do not return in the `catch` block.